# Integração com GIT

Tags: c#, git

Gostaria de saber se o Git fornece uma API de integração, tipo estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em C# e gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de pegar os arquivos do último *Commit*. Dei uma olhada no site do GIT, mas não encontrei nada a respeito.

Eu acredito que tenha como, pois como foram criados os *clients* como GitHub e plugins para o VS.

Se tiver como e for simples, postar um exemplo, senão, postar um link sobre o assunto.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tem:

> https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp

Aliás, ela tem também pacote NuGet, se sua solução usa pacotes:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibGit2Sharp